# Configuração de permalink no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tenho o seguinte link:

http://bettercallsaul.com.br/saiu-novo-teaser-de-better-call-saul/

Que leva para um post, esse post está na categoria **vídeos** que criei, gostaria de saber como faço para incluir a categoria no link?

Por exemplo:

http://bettercallsaul.com.br/`videos/`saiu-novo-teaser-de-better-call-saul/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ADM do Wordpress vá em `Configurações -> Links Permanentes` e crie uma estrutura personalizada como: `/%category%/%postname%/`

Comment: O `category` vai pegar qual categoria? por exemplo, se no post eu marcar 3 categorias, qual será a que irá aparecer?

Answer (score 0):

Felipe,

Desculpa criar uma nova resposta, mas como sou noobinho no stackoverflow pt, ainda não posso comentar.

O `/%category%/%postname%/` vai pegar **TODAS** as categorias que você tiver atribuído ao post. É por isso que é recomendado usar uma só categoria e várias tags (caso a estrutura seja igual a essa).

No entanto, recomendo que você continue com o permalink anterior. Pois além de ser mais SEO-friendly, ele também é menos "pesado" para o servidor.

Comment: Obrigado. Uma dúvida: por padrão ele pega qual categoria? pois dessa forma ele pega apenas uma.

Comment: Geralmente, a primeira associada. :)